# How to analysis big jvm dump files

Tags: jvm, large-files, dump

Our hadoop cluster has 1000+ nodes and 20PB data. So , our NameNode dump files is over 100GB and we find it is hard to analysis it by any tools.
Do any one has any suggestions about how to analysis such big jvm dump files?

Answer (score 0):

MAT is analysis the dump file with index files, can you mapped the big file into many little file and store the index files to a common file system(eg: fastdfs)